# Is this code outdated? How to write member function definitions

Tags: c++, member-functions

Bear with me here, I'm a newbie so I'll do quite a write-up to include the stuff you need to understand this. I don't understand the error so I try to describe what I know.

I'm learning C++ using the book *Beginning C++ Through Game Programming*, by Michael Dawson. It's going fine thus far, but here I encountered a problem that I think is because the code in the book is an older version of code than is currently used. I've been able to compile this code in Visual Studio Express 2013, the version used in the book.

The code in the book uses the Critter class name as a prefix to functions of that class. The definitions I have do that still, but at one point in the book, the Critter prefix is used for the function declaration, to the overloaded assignment op. When I tried in VS 2022 it generated an error:

> C++ qualified name is not allowed in member declaration

I searched on this site and found that this sort of prefix is now outdated, and I've removed the Critter:: prefix.

Removing the Critter:: prefix from the definition of the same function doesn't seem to work though, I've a bunch of new errors because the program doesn't recognize the `operator=()` as a member function. So my question, is there a way to define this function that corresponds to the modern declaration without a Critter:: prefix?

I include as much as I've written of the program, but it's not the full program as intended by the author. I'd be thankful for your help with this.

```
// Heap Data Member
// Demonstrates an object with a dynamically allocated data member

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Critter {
public:
    Critter(const string& name = "", int age = 0);
    ~Critter();                     // destructor prototype
    Critter(const Critter& c);      // copy constructor prototype
    Critter& operator=(const Critter& c);   // overloaded assignment op
    void Greet() const;
private:
    string* m_pName;
    int m_Age;
};

Critter::Critter(const string& name, int age) {
    cout << "Constructor called\n";
    m_pName = new string(name);
    m_Age = age;
}

Critter::~Critter() {                   // destructor definition
    cout << "Destructor called\n";
    delete m_pName;
}

Critter::Critter(const Critter& c) {    // copy constructor definition
    cout << "Copy Constructor called\n";
    m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
    m_Age = c.m_Age;
}

Critter& operator=(const Critter& c)    {   // overloaded assignment op def
    cout << "Overloaded Assignment Operator called\n";
    if (this != &c) {
        delete m_pName;
        m_pName = new string(*(c.m_pName));
        m_Age = c.m_Age;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Should be `Critter& Critter::operator=(const Critter& c) {`

Comment: `I searched on this site and found that this sort of prefix is now outdated, and I've removed the Critter:: prefix.` Huh?

Comment: Are you perhaps thinking of `bool operator==(Critter const& left, Critter const& right)` ?

Comment: As a general note, the book is **definitely** outdated, if it suggests `string* m_pName` with `new` and `delete`. The point of `std::string` is that it saves you from doing `new[] char` and `delete[]`. You should just write `std::string m_Name;`

Comment: You are mixing member fn definition with member fn declaration. You have to put in the TU were you have the definition, except the cases when you are defining it implicitly inline. You've got the error "C++ qualified name is not allowed in member declaration" because you used it in the declaration Critter& ***Critter***::operator=(const Critter& c);   // overloaded assignment op. Implicit inline member fn = A function defined within a class definition.

Comment: thanks guys, I'm sorry I wasted your time on this. I was confused because the book had a Critter:: prefix for the member fn declaration that generated an error for me. I could do without that, and that solved the declaration error. I think I understand it, because that specifier was redundant to use in the class itself. But I needed to use the Critter:: prefix later on when defining the function, outside of it's class. So thank you for looking at this, now I get what's wrong and it's working again